# How to convert a list of objects to nested objects after comparing key

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, object

Objective: To get the list of objects into a nested object based on its parent value.

**Here I have below my `json` data:**

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": "coding-825x500",
      "source": {
        "information": {
          "fileid": "coding-825x500",
          "filesize": 67340
        },
        **"dependent": "d1bc270d"**
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "d1bc270d",
      "source": {
        "information": {
          "fileid": "d1bc270d",
          "filesize": 193
        },
        "dependent": "parent"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1_iwPLQ",
      "source": {
        "information": {
          "fileid": "1_iwPLQ",
          "filesize": 580969
        },
        "dependent": "d1bc270d"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "coding-825",
      "source": {
        "information": {
          "fileid": "coding-825",
          "filesize": 67340
        },
        "dependent": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here in every object we have **id & dependent**

```
{ 
  "id": A
   "dependent":parent
},
{ 
  "id": B
   "dependent":A
},
{ 
  "id": C
   "dependent":A
},
{ 
  "id": D
   "dependent":null
}
```

If the id is equal to the dependent id, then it should be the child and if the dependent is the parent then `id == dependent` has to come under this and if dependent is null then it is also a parent with no children.

Below I worked using filter but later I am not sure how to proceed and create nested objects.

```
let info = this.dynamic.data.filter((val)=>{
     console.log(val.id, ":::" ,val.source.dependent);
   })
```

Stackblitz =>  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvcea7

Desired output: all the child objects should be under the parent for setting up nested data, the table may be like the format below.

```
  {

        "id": "A",
        "dependent":parent

        "nested":[

           {

                "id":"B",

                "dependent":"A"

            },
             {

                "id":"c",

                "dependent":"A"

            },



        ]

    },
     {

        "id": "c",
        "dependent":null


    }
```

Comment: can you sher the desired output? Then, it would be easy to visualize what you want.

Comment: @YogeshPatil updated question

Comment: why the first data? why ``parent` and `null`? why not use for all a unique flag, like `null` or `undefined`? is the data sorted?

Comment: @NinaScholz here if we are mentioning dependent:parent becoz it have objects which contains it is id and other as null bcoz it's id does not contain in any other dependents

Comment: but technically there is no difference, because the parent is for all not given. you mix up with descedents, but this information in the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a tree and use for nodes with `'parent'` an uniform `null` value.

This approach works for unsorted data as well.

```js
var data = [{ id: 'A', dependent: 'parent' }, { id: 'B', dependent: 'A' }, { id: 'D', dependent: null }, { id: 'C', dependent: 'A' }],
    tree = function (data) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            var parent = o.dependent === 'parent' ? null : o.dependent;
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            t[parent] = t[parent] || {};
            t[parent].nested = t[parent].nested || [];
            t[parent].nested.push(t[o.id]);
        });
        return t.null.nested;
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With the first data set. The `dependent` property is nested in an other object.

```js
var data = [{ id: "coding-825x500", source: { information: { fileid: "coding-825x500", filesize: 67340 }, dependent: "d1bc270d" } }, { id: "d1bc270d", source: { information: { fileid: "d1bc270d", filesize: 193 }, dependent: "parent" } }, { id: "1_iwPLQ", source: { information: { fileid: "1_iwPLQ", filesize: 580969 }, dependent: "d1bc270d" } }, { id: "coding-825", source: { information: { fileid: "coding-825", filesize: 67340 }, dependent: null } }],
    tree = function (data) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            var parent = o.source.dependent === 'parent' ? null : o.source.dependent;
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            t[parent] = t[parent] || { id: parent, source: null };
            t[parent].nested = t[parent].nested || [];
            t[parent].nested.push(t[o.id]);
        });
        return t.null.nested;
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i did the same but getting an error below is my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvcea7    Property 'null' does not exist on type '{}'

Comment: `dependent` is nested in `source`. please have a look to hte second approach with the first data set.

Comment: i don't understand.

Comment: in the your first approach we got result like this  [
  {
    "id": "A",
    "dependent": "parent",
    "nested": [
      {
        "id": "B",
        "dependent": "A"
      },
      {
        "id": "C",
        "dependent": "A"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "D",
    "dependent": null
  }
] where as in you second approach  we got nested  key first

Comment: right. this is possible if the children is before the parent in the data array. if you like to get the same order of properties, you could use an template object with all properties of the first level set to `null`. please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use array reduce function to acheive this.

```js
var data = [{"id": "coding-825x500","source": {"information": {"fileid": "coding-25x500","filesize": 67340},"dependent": "d1bc270d"}},{"id": "d1bc270d","source": {"information": {"fileid": "d1bc270d","filesize": 193},"dependent": "parent"}},{"id": "1_iwPLQ","source": {"information": {"fileid": "1_iwPLQ","filesize": 580969},"dependent": "d1bc270d"}},{"id": "coding-825","source": {"information": {"fileid": "coding-825","filesize": 67340},"dependent": null}}];
var result = data.reduce(function(acc, elem) {
    if( elem.source.dependent === 'parent') {
      var dependents = data.filter(function(a) { return a.source.dependent ===elem.id});
      if( dependents && dependents.length ) {
          elem.nested = elem.nested || [];
          (dependents || []).forEach(function(d) {
              elem.nested.push(d);
          })
         acc.push(elem);
      } else {
          acc.push(elem);
      }
  } else if( elem.source.dependent === null) {
      acc.push(elem);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

PS. This is not optimized to the fullest extent possible.